# How to increment/decrements value of a dynamically generated text boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

I have a e-commerce website in Magento, for that on cart page I want to add + - button to increment and decrements values of dynamically generated text boxes of quantity. I have this much code which is working fine on localhost but its not working properly on live website

```
     <tr>
     <td>
       <input type="button" class="down" value="Down" data-min="0"/>
       <input type="text" class="incdec" value="0"/>
        <input type="button" class="up" value="Up" data-max="5"/>
    </td>
</tr>


     <tr>
     <td>
     <input type="button" class="down" value="Down" data-min="0"/>
      <input type="text" class="incdec" value="0"/>
      <input type="button" class="up" value="Up" data-max="5"/>
    <td>
   </tr>
```

and here is script

```
          <script>
             $(document).ready(function() {
         $(".up").on('click',function(){
         var $incdec = $(this).parent().find(".incdec");
         if ($incdec.val() < $(this).data("max")) {
          $incdec.val(parseInt($incdec.val())+1);
         }
     });

   $(".down").on('click',function(){
      var $incdec = $(this).parent().find(".incdec");
      if ($incdec.val() > $(this).data("min")) {
        $incdec.val(parseInt($incdec.val())-1);
      }
     });
    });
          </script>
```

For suitability I also attach a screen shot for what I'm looking for.

[image]

I have spent lot of time to achieve the same but I could not.

Comment: I don't have an answer to you problem, but I want to give you a heads up on your approach. Please take into account that some products can be sold in increments. For example you can have a product that can be bought in qty of `5,10,15,20...`. In this case, the `+1` button should be `+5`.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
         $(".up").on('click',function(){
         var $incdec = $(this).prev();
         if ($incdec.val() < $(this).data("max")) {
          $incdec.val(parseInt($incdec.val())+1);
         }
     });

   $(".down").on('click',function(){
      var $incdec = $(this).next();
      if ($incdec.val() > $(this).data("min")) {
        $incdec.val(parseInt($incdec.val())-1);
      }
     });
    });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mail2asik/M8JTP/

Comment: its not working as per the need.no change in its behavior..its working as previously.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine - it's just that your HTML is not valid.

```
<table> 
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="button" class="down" value="Down" data-min="0"/>
            <input type="text" class="incdec" value="0"/>
            <input type="button" class="up" value="Up" data-max="5"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="button" class="down" value="Down" data-min="0"/>
            <input type="text" class="incdec" value="0"/>
            <input type="button" class="up" value="Up" data-max="5"/>
        <td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: it can be but how can u say that? .. in source code i checked opening and closing tag is correct in table structure

Comment: You actually have a `<div>` tag in between `<tr>`s. That is invalid in html tables.

Comment: this is just a sample code, on the live site there is no such div is available inside table. but this sample code is working fine on localhost. if its html is not valid then it should not work on localhost also

Answer (score 0):

if elements wasnt in DOM before script start, they be "unseen" for this script. try to set listener with "live" style - throw the element which was in DOM, example:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document.body).on("click", ".up", function(){
    var $incdec = $(this).parent().find(".incdec");
    if ($incdec.val() < $(this).data("max")) {
      $incdec.val(parseInt($incdec.val())+1);
    }
  });

  $(document.body).on("click", ".down", function(){
    var $incdec = $(this).parent().find(".incdec");
    if ($incdec.val() > $(this).data("min")) {
      $incdec.val(parseInt($incdec.val())-1);
    }
  });


});
</script>
```

P.S. and alse in answer near: delete "div" - it's not valid, to use div between rows of table

Comment: whenever i reload that page its qty value automatically get set to 5 i.e max value

Comment: i guess u missed the semicolon after closing of document.body. is it ?

Comment: i cant understand. you NEED to set values of qty equal to "data-max" than page is load, or values already sets to "data-max" automaticaly, and this is bad?

Comment: and also try to parseInt data("min") and data("max")

Comment: i dont want to set values of qty equals to data-max, data-max and data-min is jst a maximum and minimum value it should have.otherwise qty value should not change by clicking on up and down button

Comment: can you show console log error? open website in google chrome, in right click menu chose "inspect element" and in than chose console.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://test.outletzon.com/skin/frontend/base/default/js/carousel-min.js
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function prototype.js:5653
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (index):1556
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined form.js:178
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function prototype.js:5653
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function prototype.js:5734
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

Comment: O_O... first you should resolve all this errors! you "+/- function" maybe was ok from the begining - it's just can't start, cause script stoped by other errors. good luck)

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

> $(this).data("min") with $(this).attr("data-min")

and $

> (this).data("max") with $(this).attr("data-max")

and check.

Also is the reference to jquery file same in both localhost and in live website?

Also like "denat" told using div inside table is not valid